# Extjs 7.2.0 - Remote Filtering problem with multiple filters on same field

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I have an Ext grid and store. The store fields are

```
fields: ['id', {
  name: 'name',
  type: 'string'
}, {
  name: 'dob',
  type: 'date'
}]
```

The relevant grid column for date is set as

```
{
  xtype: 'datecolumn',
  dataIndex: 'dob',
  text: 'Date of Birth',
  format: 'd-m-Y',
  filter: 'date'
}
```

Here, the `filter` attribute is for the [gridfilters plugin](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.Filters.html).

I would also like to have the filters applied programmatically on the `dob` field like so -

```
store.filter([{
  property: 'dob',
  value: new '01/17/1990',
  operators: 'gt'
},{
  property: 'dob',
  value: '01/17/2022',
  operators: 'lt'
}])
```

However, although the `gridfilter` plugin works with multiple filters on the same field, programmatically this doesn't. It only applies the last filter from the array.

With the `gridfilter` plugin, I get multiple filters like -

```
[
  {
    "property": "dob",
    "operator": "lt",
    "value": "18/01/1990"
  },
  {
    "property": "dob",
    "operator": "gt",
    "value": "18/01/2022"
  }
]
```

However, when I try it programmatically, I only get -

```
[
  {
    "property": "dob",
    "operator": "gt",
    "value": "18/01/2022"
  }
]
```

Any suggestions toward this will be very helpful.

I've created a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate the issue.
[Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3i54)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple filters for the same property by setting a different `id` property for the filters. Change this in your code:

```
if (from && to){
    var filters = [{
        id: 1,
        property: 'dob',
        operator: 'gt',
        value: from
    },{
        id: 2,
        property: 'dob',
        operator: 'lt',
        value: to
    }]

    store.filter(filters);
}
```

If you change it in your fiddle, under `Filters Applied` you will see that both filters are set this way. Anyway, I think you need to adjust this a bit to actually work, because your dates are stored currently as text.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps solve that. With regard to "because your dates are stored currently as text", I wanted to put up something quickly. Will fix that also.

Comment: You are welcome. Note1: `id` is a string according to the documentation. Note2: after this, if you want to remove one of the filters with `removeFilter`, you need to use this `id` and not the `property` as normally, because `property` is not unique.